# VIM arrow keys with sudo

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I have identical `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files. When I `sudo vim <file>` in insert mode the arrow keys create a, b, c ,d instead of going left/right/up/down.

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from [this Vim Tips Wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell)?

Comment: Why has this two down votes? It's a simple question that is well formulated, and asked because the arrow keys behave this way when I sudo a file. This is a joke, now I have been banned to ask further questions.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I voted to move this to Super User, because it's mostly an environment / configuration issue, and not related to using Vim in a programming context, so it doesn't fit in here well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `sudo vim <file>` you are running vim as the sudo user, so your users `.vimrc` is not being loaded, and the sudo user does not have a `.vimrc` of its own. You should see the same behavior with `vim -u NONE`.

The solution is to do the following:

```
:set nocompatible
```

This is done by vim implicitly when you have a `.vimrc`.

---

An alternative to using `sudo vim <file>` is to set you `$EDITOR` environment variable to vim by adding the following to your `.bashrc`

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

Then, to edit files that require sudo premissons use: `sudo -e <file>`

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to edit the system wide configuration file.
On Ubuntu this could be one of either

- /etc/vim/vimrc.tiny
- /etc/vim/vimrc

In my system default /etc/vim/vimrc.tiny I changed

```
set compatible
```

to

```
set nocompatible
```

After this even when using sudo the arrow keys did not result in A, B, C ,D instead of going left/right/up/down.

See this link for an explanation about what "compatible" is

https://superuser.com/questions/543317/what-is-compatible-mode-in-vim